# Pegar elemento de uma string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Supondo que eu tenha:

```
<script>
 var string = "Hello [background]image.png[background] World!";
</script>
```

Teria como buscar a imagem que esta dentro dos dois `[background]`, e guardar em outra variável, por exemplo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ericki, tem como e existem inúmeras formas de fazer isso, abaixo dois exemplos de como isso pode ser feito:

```js
var string = "Hello [background]image.png[background] World!";

//Pegando o valor com regex
found = /\[background\](.*?)\[background\]/g.exec(string);

if(found) {
  //console.log(found);
  var backgroundValue1 = found[1];
  console.log(backgroundValue1);
}

//Pegando o valor procurando pelos índices...
var firstIndex = string.indexOf("[background]");

if(firstIndex) {

  //Remove o começo da string - 12 é o tamanho da palavra [background]
  var backgroundValue2 = string.substr(firstIndex + 12, string.length);

  //Remove o final da string
  backgroundValue2 = backgroundValue2.substr(0, backgroundValue2.lastIndexOf("[background]"));

  console.log(backgroundValue2);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!

Answer (score 1):

Outra forma é usando `.split()` pegando o índice `[1]`:

```js
var string = "Hello [background]image.png[background] World!";
var novo = string.split("[background]")[1];
console.log(novo);
```